# How do physicists explain the power requirements of relative motion?

Tags: relativity

It is simple to understand that, for example, when a rocket leaves the Earth that, from the frame of reference of the rocket, the Earth is actually moving away.   But while it takes a certain amount of energy to accelerate a rocket, it takes a lot more energy to accelerate the Earth to the same speed. But that energy was never used. So how do we explain this conundrum?

Answer (score 5):

> it takes a lot more energy to accelerate the Earth to the same speed. But that energy was never used. So how do we explain this conundrum?

Energy is not conserved in most non inertial reference frames. Specifically, reference frames with time varying inertial forces do not conserve energy. This can be seen as a consequence of Noether’s theorem: the time varying inertial forces break the time symmetry of the Lagrangian so there is no corresponding conserved quantity.

Comment: Wow.  I knew that, in a complicated, intuitive, "I could never describe that" sort of way.  Thank you for putting it into an immediate and logical framework for me to hang my thinking on!

Comment: So if we wanted conservation of energy to hold we'd need to choose just about any inertial frame, and look at the energy expended vs. the rocket speed?

Comment: Yes, and it would work out fine in any inertial frame.

Comment: I've been pondering your answer for several days and I just don't understand.  First, you say that energy is not conserved.  So does this mean that energy can be lost OR created?  It seems from my original question that the energy of the earth's motion was created.   Second, what about after the acceleration phase when the rocket is just coasting in a line (inertial frame).  The earth is moving away at the same speed according to the rocket's frame.  Where did the Earth's energy come from in this case?

Comment: @foolishmuse "does this mean that energy can be lost OR created?" Yes, if energy is not conserved then it can be lost and/or created. It can come from nothing and go to nowhere. "Where did the Earth's energy come from" it came from nothing. That is the point of non-conservation, it doesn't come from anything or anywhere. If you are asking strictly about the inertial portion of the rocket's frame then you cannot ask about anything that happened before that portion of the rocket's frame. In which case the energy was already present in the beginning (of the inertial portion).

Comment: @Dale  This is something completely new to me so I'm going to have to understand it before I can check mark your answer.  Can you point me anywhere that might help me to understand?

Answer (score 0):

"it takes a lot more energy to accelerate the Earth to the same speed" agreed, in the rockets reference frame the earth accelerate dues to both the force from the rocket and the fictitious force ($-ma_{rocket}$) due to being a non inertial system.
from the system;s center of mass the earth is barely accelerated